# Computing the multiplication of elements to generate the Cayley graph of a semidirect product

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, gap, semidirect-product, cayley-graphs

I have computed a semidirect product, $s$ of $(\mathbb{Z}_5 \times \mathbb{Z}_5) \rtimes \mathbb{Z}_3$ as below and have drawn a Cayley graph for $s$ with respect to a generating set $S$. But I wanted to compare the result I got by the CayleyGraph command, with the result I get when I multiply the elements of $s$ representing vertices of the Cayley graph by the elements in the generating set, according to the definition of the Cayley graph (there is an edge from $g$ to $gt$ for $g \in s, t \in S$).

```
gap> LogTo("C:/Users/Desktop/Test1/Ndoc15.txt");

gap> Read("C:/Users/Desktop/Test1/UndirectedGeneratingSets.gap");

gap> LoadPackage("grape");;

gap> Z3:=Group((1,2,3));
Group([ (1,2,3) ])

gap> Z3gen:=GeneratorsOfGroup(Z3)[1];
(1,2,3)

gap> Z5:=Group((1,2,3,4,5));
Group([ (1,2,3,4,5) ])

gap> h:=DirectProduct(Z5,Z5);
Group([ (1,2,3,4,5), (6,7,8,9,10) ])

gap>  Auts:=AutomorphismGroup(h);
<group with 4 generators>

gap> AutsOfOrd3:=Filtered(Elements(Auts),elt->Order(elt)=3);;

gap> ExHom:=GroupHomomorphismByImages(Z3,Auts,[Z3gen],[AutsOfOrd3[1]]);
[ (1,2,3) ] -> [ [ (1,2,3,4,5), (6,7,8,9,10) ] -> [ (1,5,4,3,2)(6,10,9,8,7), 
(1,2,3,4,5) ] ]

gap> s:=SemidirectProduct(Z3,ExHom,h);
Group([ (2,6,25)(3,11,19)(4,16,13)(5,21,7)(8,10,20)(9,15,14)(12,24,22) 
(17,18,23), (1,6,11,16,21)(2,7,12,17,22)
(3,8,13,18,23)(4,9,14,19,24)(5,10,15,20,25), (1,2,3,4,5)(6,7,8,9,10) 
(11,12,13,14,15)(16,17,18,19,20)
(21,22,23,24,25) ])

gap> S:=IrredUndirGenSetsUpToAut(s);
[ [ (2,6,25)(3,11,19)(4,16,13)(5,21,7)(8,10,20)(9,15,14)(12,24,22)(17,18,23), (1,2,3,4,5)(6,7,8,9,10)(11,12,13,14,
    15)(16,17,18,19,20)(21,22,23,24,25) ],
  [ (2,6,25)(3,11,19)(4,16,13)(5,21,7)(8,10,20)(9,15,14)(12,24,22)(17,18,23), (1,2,7)(3,12,25)(4,17,19)(5,22,13)(6,21,
    8)(9,11,20)(10,16,14)(18,24,23) ] ]

gap> S1:=S[1];
[ (2,6,25)(3,11,19)(4,16,13)(5,21,7)(8,10,20)(9,15,14)(12,24,22)(17,18,23), (1,2,3,4,5)(6,7,8,9,10)(11,12,13,14,
15)(16,17,18,19,20)(21,22,23,24,25) ]

gap> Order(S1[1]);
3

gap> Order(S1[2]);
5

gap> X1:=CayleyGraph(s,S1);
rec( adjacencies := [ [ 2, 3, 4, 13 ] ], group := <permutation group of size 75 with 3 generators>, isGraph := true,
  isSimple := true, names := [ (), (2,6,25)(3,11,19)(4,16,13)(5,21,7)(8,10,20)(9,15,14)(12,24,22)(17,18,23),
  (2,25,6)(3,19,11)(4,13,16)(5,7,21)(8,20,10)(9,14,15)(12,22,24)(17,23,18), (1,2,3,4,5)(6,7,8,9,10)(11,12,13,14,
    15)(16,17,18,19,20)(21,22,23,24,25), (1,2,7)(3,12,25)(4,17,19)(5,22,13)(6,21,8)(9,11,20)(10,16,14)(18,24,23),
  (1,2,21)(3,20,6)(4,14,11)(5,8,16)(7,22,25)(9,15,10)(12,23,19)(13,17,24), (1,3,5,2,4)(6,8,10,7,9)(11,13,15,12,
    14)(16,18,20,17,19)(21,23,25,22,24), (1,3,13)(2,8,7)(4,18,25)(5,23,19)(6,22,14)(9,12,21)(10,17,20)(11,16,15),
  (1,3,16)(2,22,21)(4,15,6)(5,9,11)(7,23,20)(8,17,25)(12,24,14)(13,18,19), (1,4,2,5,3)(6,9,7,10,8)(11,14,12,15,
    13)(16,19,17,20,18)(21,24,22,25,23), (1,4,19)(2,9,13)(3,14,7)(5,24,25)(6,23,20)(10,18,21)(11,17,16)(12,22,15),
  (1,4,11)(2,23,16)(3,17,21)(5,10,6)(7,24,15)(8,18,20)(9,12,25)(13,19,14), (1,5,4,3,2)(6,10,9,8,7)(11,15,14,13,
    12)(16,20,19,18,17)(21,25,24,23,22), (1,5,25)(2,10,19)(3,15,13)(4,20,7)(6,24,21)(8,9,14)(11,18,22)(12,23,16),
  (1,5,6)(2,24,11)(3,18,16)(4,12,21)(7,25,10)(8,19,15)(9,13,20)(17,22,23), (1,6,7)(2,5,12)(3,24,17)(4,18,22)(8,25,
    11)(9,19,16)(10,13,21)(14,20,15), (1,6,11,16,21)(2,7,12,17,22)(3,8,13,18,23)(4,9,14,19,24)(5,10,15,20,25),
  (1,6,5)(2,11,24)(3,16,18)(4,21,12)(7,10,25)(8,15,19)(9,20,13)(17,23,22), (1,7,2)(3,25,12)(4,19,17)(5,13,22)(6,8,
    21)(9,20,11)(10,14,16)(18,23,24), (1,7,13,19,25)(2,8,14,20,21)(3,9,15,16,22)(4,10,11,17,23)(5,6,12,18,24),
  (1,7,6)(2,12,5)(3,17,24)(4,22,18)(8,11,25)(9,16,19)(10,21,13)(14,15,20), (1,8,22)(3,21,7)(4,20,12)(5,14,17)(6,9,
    16)(10,15,11)(13,23,25)(18,24,19), (1,8,15,17,24)(2,9,11,18,25)(3,10,12,19,21)(4,6,13,20,22)(5,7,14,16,23),
  (1,8,12)(2,13,6)(3,18,5)(4,23,24)(9,17,25)(10,22,19)(11,21,14)(15,16,20), (1,9,17)(2,3,22)(4,16,7)(5,15,12)(6,
    10,11)(8,23,21)(13,24,20)(14,18,25), (1,9,12,20,23)(2,10,13,16,24)(3,6,14,17,25)(4,7,15,18,21)(5,8,11,19,22),
  (1,9,18)(2,14,12)(3,19,6)(4,24,5)(7,8,13)(10,23,25)(11,22,20)(15,17,21), (1,10,12)(2,4,17)(3,23,22)(5,11,7)(8,
    24,16)(9,18,21)(13,25,15)(14,19,20), (1,10,14,18,22)(2,6,15,19,23)(3,7,11,20,24)(4,8,12,16,25)(5,9,13,17,21),
  (1,10,24)(2,15,18)(3,20,12)(4,25,6)(7,9,19)(8,14,13)(11,23,21)(16,17,22), (1,11,13)(2,10,18)(3,4,23)(5,17,8)(6,
    12,7)(9,24,22)(14,25,16)(15,19,21), (1,11,21,6,16)(2,12,22,7,17)(3,13,23,8,18)(4,14,24,9,19)(5,15,25,10,20),
  (1,11,4)(2,16,23)(3,21,17)(5,6,10)(7,15,24)(8,20,18)(9,25,12)(13,14,19), (1,12,8)(2,6,13)(3,5,18)(4,24,23)(9,25,
    17)(10,19,22)(11,14,21)(15,20,16), (1,12,23,9,20)(2,13,24,10,16)(3,14,25,6,17)(4,15,21,7,18)(5,11,22,8,19),
  (1,12,10)(2,17,4)(3,22,23)(5,7,11)(8,16,24)(9,21,18)(13,15,25)(14,20,19), (1,13,3)(2,7,8)(4,25,18)(5,19,23)(6,
    14,22)(9,21,12)(10,20,17)(11,15,16), (1,13,25,7,19)(2,14,21,8,20)(3,15,22,9,16)(4,11,23,10,17)(5,12,24,6,18),
  (1,13,11)(2,18,10)(3,23,4)(5,8,17)(6,7,12)(9,22,24)(14,16,25)(15,21,19), (1,14,23)(2,8,3)(4,21,13)(5,20,18)(6,
    15,17)(7,9,22)(10,16,12)(19,24,25), (1,14,22,10,18)(2,15,23,6,19)(3,11,24,7,20)(4,12,25,8,16)(5,13,21,9,17),
  (1,14,17)(2,19,11)(3,24,10)(5,9,23)(6,8,18)(7,13,12)(15,22,25)(16,21,20), (1,15,18)(2,9,23)(4,22,8)(5,16,13)(6,
    11,12)(7,10,17)(14,24,21)(19,25,20), (1,15,24,8,17)(2,11,25,9,18)(3,12,21,10,19)(4,13,22,6,20)(5,14,23,7,16),
  (1,15,23)(2,20,17)(3,25,11)(4,5,10)(6,9,24)(7,14,18)(8,19,12)(16,22,21), (1,16,19)(2,15,24)(3,9,4)(5,22,14)(6,
    17,13)(7,11,18)(8,10,23)(20,25,21), (1,16,6,21,11)(2,17,7,22,12)(3,18,8,23,13)(4,19,9,24,14)(5,20,10,25,15),
  (1,16,3)(2,21,22)(4,6,15)(5,11,9)(7,20,23)(8,25,17)(12,14,24)(13,19,18), (1,17,14)(2,11,19)(3,10,24)(5,23,9)(6,
    18,8)(7,12,13)(15,25,22)(16,20,21), (1,17,8,24,15)(2,18,9,25,11)(3,19,10,21,12)(4,20,6,22,13)(5,16,7,23,14),
  (1,17,9)(2,22,3)(4,7,16)(5,12,15)(6,11,10)(8,21,23)(13,20,24)(14,25,18), (1,18,9)(2,12,14)(3,6,19)(4,5,24)(7,13,
    8)(10,25,23)(11,20,22)(15,21,17), (1,18,10,22,14)(2,19,6,23,15)(3,20,7,24,11)(4,16,8,25,12)(5,17,9,21,13),
  (1,18,15)(2,23,9)(4,8,22)(5,13,16)(6,12,11)(7,17,10)(14,21,24)(19,20,25), (1,19,4)(2,13,9)(3,7,14)(5,25,24)(6,
    20,23)(10,21,18)(11,16,17)(12,15,22), (1,19,7,25,13)(2,20,8,21,14)(3,16,9,22,15)(4,17,10,23,11)(5,18,6,24,12),
  (1,19,16)(2,24,15)(3,4,9)(5,14,22)(6,13,17)(7,18,11)(8,23,10)(20,21,25), (1,20,24)(2,14,4)(3,8,9)(5,21,19)(6,16,
    18)(7,15,23)(10,22,13)(11,17,12), (1,20,9,23,12)(2,16,10,24,13)(3,17,6,25,14)(4,18,7,21,15)(5,19,8,22,11),
  (1,20,22)(2,25,16)(3,5,15)(4,10,9)(6,14,23)(7,19,17)(8,24,11)(12,13,18), (1,21,2)(3,6,20)(4,11,14)(5,16,8)(7,25,
    22)(9,10,15)(12,19,23)(13,24,17), (1,21,25)(2,20,5)(3,14,10)(4,8,15)(6,22,19)(7,16,24)(11,23,13)(12,17,18),
  (1,21,16,11,6)(2,22,17,12,7)(3,23,18,13,8)(4,24,19,14,9)(5,25,20,15,10), (1,22,8)(3,7,21)(4,12,20)(5,17,14)(6,
    16,9)(10,11,15)(13,25,23)(18,19,24), (1,22,20)(2,16,25)(3,15,5)(4,9,10)(6,23,14)(7,17,19)(8,11,24)(12,18,13),
  (1,22,18,14,10)(2,23,19,15,6)(3,24,20,11,7)(4,25,16,12,8)(5,21,17,13,9), (1,23,14)(2,3,8)(4,13,21)(5,18,20)(6,
    17,15)(7,22,9)(10,12,16)(19,25,24), (1,23,15)(2,17,20)(3,11,25)(4,10,5)(6,24,9)(7,18,14)(8,12,19)(16,21,22),
  (1,23,20,12,9)(2,24,16,13,10)(3,25,17,14,6)(4,21,18,15,7)(5,22,19,11,8), (1,24,20)(2,4,14)(3,9,8)(5,19,21)(6,18,
    16)(7,23,15)(10,13,22)(11,12,17), (1,24,10)(2,18,15)(3,12,20)(4,6,25)(7,19,9)(8,13,14)(11,21,23)(16,22,17),
  (1,24,17,15,8)(2,25,18,11,9)(3,21,19,12,10)(4,22,20,13,6)(5,23,16,14,7), (1,25,21)(2,5,20)(3,10,14)(4,15,8)(6,
    19,22)(7,24,16)(11,13,23)(12,18,17), (1,25,5)(2,19,10)(3,13,15)(4,7,20)(6,21,24)(8,14,9)(11,22,18)(12,16,23),
  (1,25,19,13,7)(2,21,20,14,8)(3,22,16,15,9)(4,23,17,11,10)(5,24,18,12,6) ], order := 75,
  representatives := [ 1 ], schreierVector := [ -1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
  3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1,
  3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1 ] )

gap> A:=VertexNames(X1);
[ (), (2,6,25)(3,11,19)(4,16,13)(5,21,7)(8,10,20)(9,15,14)(12,24,22)(17,18,23), (2,25,6)(3,19,11)(4,13,16)(5,7,21)(8,
20,10)(9,14,15)(12,22,24)(17,23,18), (1,2,3,4,5)(6,7,8,9,10)(11,12,13,14,15)(16,17,18,19,20)(21,22,23,24,25),
  (1,2,7)(3,12,25)(4,17,19)(5,22,13)(6,21,8)(9,11,20)(10,16,14)(18,24,23), (1,2,21)(3,20,6)(4,14,11)(5,8,16)(7,22,
25)(9,15,10)(12,23,19)(13,17,24), (1,3,5,2,4)(6,8,10,7,9)(11,13,15,12,14)(16,18,20,17,19)(21,23,25,22,24),
  (1,3,13)(2,8,7)(4,18,25)(5,23,19)(6,22,14)(9,12,21)(10,17,20)(11,16,15), (1,3,16)(2,22,21)(4,15,6)(5,9,11)(7,23,
20)(8,17,25)(12,24,14)(13,18,19), (1,4,2,5,3)(6,9,7,10,8)(11,14,12,15,13)(16,19,17,20,18)(21,24,22,25,23),
  (1,4,19)(2,9,13)(3,14,7)(5,24,25)(6,23,20)(10,18,21)(11,17,16)(12,22,15), (1,4,11)(2,23,16)(3,17,21)(5,10,6)(7,24,
15)(8,18,20)(9,12,25)(13,19,14), (1,5,4,3,2)(6,10,9,8,7)(11,15,14,13,12)(16,20,19,18,17)(21,25,24,23,22),
  (1,5,25)(2,10,19)(3,15,13)(4,20,7)(6,24,21)(8,9,14)(11,18,22)(12,23,16), (1,5,6)(2,24,11)(3,18,16)(4,12,21)(7,25,
10)(8,19,15)(9,13,20)(17,22,23), (1,6,7)(2,5,12)(3,24,17)(4,18,22)(8,25,11)(9,19,16)(10,13,21)(14,20,15),
  (1,6,11,16,21)(2,7,12,17,22)(3,8,13,18,23)(4,9,14,19,24)(5,10,15,20,25), (1,6,5)(2,11,24)(3,16,18)(4,21,12)(7,10,
25)(8,15,19)(9,20,13)(17,23,22), (1,7,2)(3,25,12)(4,19,17)(5,13,22)(6,8,21)(9,20,11)(10,14,16)(18,23,24),
  (1,7,13,19,25)(2,8,14,20,21)(3,9,15,16,22)(4,10,11,17,23)(5,6,12,18,24), (1,7,6)(2,12,5)(3,17,24)(4,22,18)(8,11,
25)(9,16,19)(10,21,13)(14,15,20), (1,8,22)(3,21,7)(4,20,12)(5,14,17)(6,9,16)(10,15,11)(13,23,25)(18,24,19),
  (1,8,15,17,24)(2,9,11,18,25)(3,10,12,19,21)(4,6,13,20,22)(5,7,14,16,23), (1,8,12)(2,13,6)(3,18,5)(4,23,24)(9,17,
25)(10,22,19)(11,21,14)(15,16,20), (1,9,17)(2,3,22)(4,16,7)(5,15,12)(6,10,11)(8,23,21)(13,24,20)(14,18,25),
  (1,9,12,20,23)(2,10,13,16,24)(3,6,14,17,25)(4,7,15,18,21)(5,8,11,19,22), (1,9,18)(2,14,12)(3,19,6)(4,24,5)(7,8,
13)(10,23,25)(11,22,20)(15,17,21), (1,10,12)(2,4,17)(3,23,22)(5,11,7)(8,24,16)(9,18,21)(13,25,15)(14,19,20),
  (1,10,14,18,22)(2,6,15,19,23)(3,7,11,20,24)(4,8,12,16,25)(5,9,13,17,21), (1,10,24)(2,15,18)(3,20,12)(4,25,6)(7,9,
19)(8,14,13)(11,23,21)(16,17,22), (1,11,13)(2,10,18)(3,4,23)(5,17,8)(6,12,7)(9,24,22)(14,25,16)(15,19,21),
  (1,11,21,6,16)(2,12,22,7,17)(3,13,23,8,18)(4,14,24,9,19)(5,15,25,10,20), (1,11,4)(2,16,23)(3,21,17)(5,6,10)(7,15,
24)(8,20,18)(9,25,12)(13,14,19), (1,12,8)(2,6,13)(3,5,18)(4,24,23)(9,25,17)(10,19,22)(11,14,21)(15,20,16),
  (1,12,23,9,20)(2,13,24,10,16)(3,14,25,6,17)(4,15,21,7,18)(5,11,22,8,19), (1,12,10)(2,17,4)(3,22,23)(5,7,11)(8,16,
24)(9,21,18)(13,15,25)(14,20,19), (1,13,3)(2,7,8)(4,25,18)(5,19,23)(6,14,22)(9,21,12)(10,20,17)(11,15,16),
  (1,13,25,7,19)(2,14,21,8,20)(3,15,22,9,16)(4,11,23,10,17)(5,12,24,6,18), (1,13,11)(2,18,10)(3,23,4)(5,8,17)(6,7,
12)(9,22,24)(14,16,25)(15,21,19), (1,14,23)(2,8,3)(4,21,13)(5,20,18)(6,15,17)(7,9,22)(10,16,12)(19,24,25),
  (1,14,22,10,18)(2,15,23,6,19)(3,11,24,7,20)(4,12,25,8,16)(5,13,21,9,17), (1,14,17)(2,19,11)(3,24,10)(5,9,23)(6,8,
18)(7,13,12)(15,22,25)(16,21,20), (1,15,18)(2,9,23)(4,22,8)(5,16,13)(6,11,12)(7,10,17)(14,24,21)(19,25,20),
  (1,15,24,8,17)(2,11,25,9,18)(3,12,21,10,19)(4,13,22,6,20)(5,14,23,7,16), (1,15,23)(2,20,17)(3,25,11)(4,5,10)(6,9,
24)(7,14,18)(8,19,12)(16,22,21), (1,16,19)(2,15,24)(3,9,4)(5,22,14)(6,17,13)(7,11,18)(8,10,23)(20,25,21),
  (1,16,6,21,11)(2,17,7,22,12)(3,18,8,23,13)(4,19,9,24,14)(5,20,10,25,15), (1,16,3)(2,21,22)(4,6,15)(5,11,9)(7,20,
23)(8,25,17)(12,14,24)(13,19,18), (1,17,14)(2,11,19)(3,10,24)(5,23,9)(6,18,8)(7,12,13)(15,25,22)(16,20,21),
  (1,17,8,24,15)(2,18,9,25,11)(3,19,10,21,12)(4,20,6,22,13)(5,16,7,23,14), (1,17,9)(2,22,3)(4,7,16)(5,12,15)(6,11,
10)(8,21,23)(13,20,24)(14,25,18), (1,18,9)(2,12,14)(3,6,19)(4,5,24)(7,13,8)(10,25,23)(11,20,22)(15,21,17),
  (1,18,10,22,14)(2,19,6,23,15)(3,20,7,24,11)(4,16,8,25,12)(5,17,9,21,13), (1,18,15)(2,23,9)(4,8,22)(5,13,16)(6,12,
11)(7,17,10)(14,21,24)(19,20,25), (1,19,4)(2,13,9)(3,7,14)(5,25,24)(6,20,23)(10,21,18)(11,16,17)(12,15,22),
  (1,19,7,25,13)(2,20,8,21,14)(3,16,9,22,15)(4,17,10,23,11)(5,18,6,24,12), (1,19,16)(2,24,15)(3,4,9)(5,14,22)(6,13,
17)(7,18,11)(8,23,10)(20,21,25), (1,20,24)(2,14,4)(3,8,9)(5,21,19)(6,16,18)(7,15,23)(10,22,13)(11,17,12),
  (1,20,9,23,12)(2,16,10,24,13)(3,17,6,25,14)(4,18,7,21,15)(5,19,8,22,11), (1,20,22)(2,25,16)(3,5,15)(4,10,9)(6,14,
23)(7,19,17)(8,24,11)(12,13,18), (1,21,2)(3,6,20)(4,11,14)(5,16,8)(7,25,22)(9,10,15)(12,19,23)(13,24,17),
  (1,21,25)(2,20,5)(3,14,10)(4,8,15)(6,22,19)(7,16,24)(11,23,13)(12,17,18), (1,21,16,11,6)(2,22,17,12,7)(3,23,18,13,
8)(4,24,19,14,9)(5,25,20,15,10), (1,22,8)(3,7,21)(4,12,20)(5,17,14)(6,16,9)(10,11,15)(13,25,23)(18,19,24),
  (1,22,20)(2,16,25)(3,15,5)(4,9,10)(6,23,14)(7,17,19)(8,11,24)(12,18,13), (1,22,18,14,10)(2,23,19,15,6)(3,24,20,11,
7)(4,25,16,12,8)(5,21,17,13,9), (1,23,14)(2,3,8)(4,13,21)(5,18,20)(6,17,15)(7,22,9)(10,12,16)(19,25,24),
  (1,23,15)(2,17,20)(3,11,25)(4,10,5)(6,24,9)(7,18,14)(8,12,19)(16,21,22), (1,23,20,12,9)(2,24,16,13,10)(3,25,17,14,
6)(4,21,18,15,7)(5,22,19,11,8), (1,24,20)(2,4,14)(3,9,8)(5,19,21)(6,18,16)(7,23,15)(10,13,22)(11,12,17),
  (1,24,10)(2,18,15)(3,12,20)(4,6,25)(7,19,9)(8,13,14)(11,21,23)(16,22,17), (1,24,17,15,8)(2,25,18,11,9)(3,21,19,12,
10)(4,22,20,13,6)(5,23,16,14,7), (1,25,21)(2,5,20)(3,10,14)(4,15,8)(6,19,22)(7,24,16)(11,13,23)(12,18,17),
  (1,25,5)(2,19,10)(3,13,15)(4,7,20)(6,21,24)(8,14,9)(11,22,18)(12,16,23), (1,25,19,13,7)(2,21,20,14,8)(3,22,16,15,
9)(4,23,17,11,10)(5,24,18,12,6) ]
gap> B1:=A[1]*S1[1];
(2,6,25)(3,11,19)(4,16,13)(5,21,7)(8,10,20)(9,15,14)(12,24,22)(17,18,23)
gap> B2:=B1*S1[2];
(1,2,7)(3,12,25)(4,17,19)(5,22,13)(6,21,8)(9,11,20)(10,16,14)(18,24,23)
gap> C:=[B1,B2];
[ (2,6,25)(3,11,19)(4,16,13)(5,21,7)(8,10,20)(9,15,14)(12,24,22)(17,18,23), 
(1,2,7)(3,12,25)(4,17,19)(5,22,13)(6,21,
8)(9,11,20)(10,16,14)(18,24,23) ]

gap> C1:=[A[2],A[18]];
[ (2,6,25)(3,11,19)(4,16,13)(5,21,7)(8,10,20)(9,15,14)(12,24,22)(17,18,23), 
(1,6,5)(2,11,24)(3,16,18)(4,21,12)(7,10,
25)(8,15,19)(9,20,13)(17,23,22) ]

gap> UndirectedEdges(X1);
[ [ 1, 2 ], [ 1, 3 ], [ 1, 4 ], [ 1, 13 ], [ 2, 3 ], [ 2, 18 ], [ 2, 61 ], [ 3, 19 ], [ 3, 74 ], [ 4, 5 ], [ 4, 6 ],
  [ 4, 7 ], [ 5, 6 ], [ 5, 21 ], [ 5, 64 ], [ 6, 22 ], [ 6, 62 ], [ 7, 8 ], [ 7, 9 ], [ 7, 10 ], [ 8, 9 ], [ 8, 24 ],
  [ 8, 67 ], [ 9, 25 ], [ 9, 65 ], [ 10, 11 ], [ 10, 12 ], [ 10, 13 ], [ 11, 12 ], [ 11, 27 ], [ 11, 70 ],
  [ 12, 28 ], [ 12, 68 ], [ 13, 14 ], [ 13, 15 ], [ 14, 15 ], [ 14, 30 ], [ 14, 73 ], [ 15, 16 ], [ 15, 71 ],
  [ 16, 17 ], [ 16, 18 ], [ 16, 34 ], [ 17, 18 ], [ 17, 20 ], [ 17, 29 ], [ 18, 33 ], [ 19, 20 ], [ 19, 21 ],
  [ 19, 37 ], [ 20, 21 ], [ 20, 23 ], [ 21, 36 ], [ 22, 23 ], [ 22, 24 ], [ 22, 40 ], [ 23, 24 ], [ 23, 26 ],
  [ 24, 39 ], [ 25, 26 ], [ 25, 27 ], [ 25, 43 ], [ 26, 27 ], [ 26, 29 ], [ 27, 42 ], [ 28, 29 ], [ 28, 30 ],
  [ 28, 31 ], [ 29, 30 ], [ 30, 45 ], [ 31, 32 ], [ 31, 33 ], [ 31, 49 ], [ 32, 33 ], [ 32, 35 ], [ 32, 44 ],
  [ 33, 48 ], [ 34, 35 ], [ 34, 36 ], [ 34, 52 ], [ 35, 36 ], [ 35, 38 ], [ 36, 51 ], [ 37, 38 ], [ 37, 39 ],
  [ 37, 55 ], [ 38, 39 ], [ 38, 41 ], [ 39, 54 ], [ 40, 41 ], [ 40, 42 ], [ 40, 58 ], [ 41, 42 ], [ 41, 44 ],
  [ 42, 57 ], [ 43, 44 ], [ 43, 45 ], [ 43, 46 ], [ 44, 45 ], [ 45, 60 ], [ 46, 47 ], [ 46, 48 ], [ 46, 65 ],
  [ 47, 48 ], [ 47, 50 ], [ 47, 59 ], [ 48, 61 ], [ 49, 50 ], [ 49, 51 ], [ 49, 68 ], [ 50, 51 ], [ 50, 53 ],
  [ 51, 64 ], [ 52, 53 ], [ 52, 54 ], [ 52, 71 ], [ 53, 54 ], [ 53, 56 ], [ 54, 67 ], [ 55, 56 ], [ 55, 57 ],
  [ 55, 74 ], [ 56, 57 ], [ 56, 59 ], [ 57, 70 ], [ 58, 59 ], [ 58, 60 ], [ 58, 62 ], [ 59, 60 ], [ 60, 73 ],
  [ 61, 62 ], [ 61, 63 ], [ 62, 63 ], [ 63, 66 ], [ 63, 75 ], [ 64, 65 ], [ 64, 66 ], [ 65, 66 ], [ 66, 69 ],
  [ 67, 68 ], [ 67, 69 ], [ 68, 69 ], [ 69, 72 ], [ 70, 71 ], [ 70, 72 ], [ 71, 72 ], [ 72, 75 ], [ 73, 74 ],
  [ 73, 75 ], [ 74, 75 ] ]
```

Then when I compute A[1]*S1[1] which is the vertex number 2 in Cayley graph, and then multiply it again by S1[2], I get the value of the vertex number 5 instead of vertex number 18, which should be the correct one according to the list of Undirected edges.

My question is why am I getting an edge from 2 to 5 instead of 2 to 18? Is there something missing when I take the multiplication of elements of the semidirect product?

Please help me with this question.

Definition of Cayley graph:

Let $G$ be a group and $S \subseteq G$ be a generating set of $G$. The Cayley digraph of $G$ with respect to $S$, $X=\overrightarrow{Cay}(G,\: S)$ is a graph whose vertices are the elements of $G$ and there is an edge from $g$ to $gs$ whenever $g \in G$ and $s \in S$. The Cayley graph, $X=Cay(G,\: S)$ is the undirected graph whose vertices are the elements of $G$ and there is an edge from $g$ to $gs$ and from $g$ to $gs^{-1}$ whenever $g \in G$ and $s \in S$.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You are giving hundred lines of system transcript, using a function that is not known. I don't think it is plausible to expect a response. I suggest you try: - Explain why you expect a certain result, and in what way it fails. Do so in an exampel of minimal size. Leave out commands and output that is not relevant.

Comment: Relevant [meta post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30315) on coding problem.

Comment: Thank you @ahulpke I have edited the question now. Please be kind enough to advice.

Comment: I haven't read the details and I am not planning to do so, but I wonder whether the problem is somehow resulting from the fact that GAP uses right actions whereas the majority of mathematicians (for some strange reason) seem to use left actions.

Comment: @billy Adding a  definition does not really address the problem in the question (namely that it only makes assertions and then  asks to "find the mistake"). What have you tried to find the error? What makes you believe there is a bug? Have you traced through the steps by hand and checked where a problem arises first? As for the problem, I suspect that you make assumptions about indices that do not hold. The best way of debugging this is to start with smaller examples (try nonabelian groups of order 6-12) and to check whether all your assumptions hold for the calculations there.

Comment: But @ahulpke I still do not understand. And I don't have a proper idea on how to approach and start working on the smaller example. The question I'm having is, when I multiply A[2] by S1[2], which is the generating element of order 5, it gives me the value of A[5] instead of A[18]. And according to the list there should be and edge between vertex 2 and 18.

Comment: I checked by taking the elements of the semidirect product $s$ and there I multiplied the element which is A[2] according to above question by the element S[2] but the result was the same, I get the value of A[5] (according to above A)

Comment: I am doing the right action, and I took the indices of the vertices by considering the order in which they appear in VertexNames in the Cayley graph. Please be kind enough to help me to understand and advice me in this regard. Thanks a lot in advance.